# Displaying the ID on the login form upon button press

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1v8C.png)

How do I display the loginID after I entered the username and password before the library form is shown?

```
    Dim login = Me.LoginTableAdapter1.UserPasswordString(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text)

    If login Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Incorrect User/Password")
    Else

        MsgBox("Welcome, you are now logged in")
        Me.Hide()
        frmLibrary.Show()


    End If
```

---

```
SELECT        COUNT(*) AS Result, username AS UsernameInput, password AS PasswordInput
FROM            Login
GROUP BY username, password
HAVING        (COUNT(*) = 1) AND (username = @user) AND (password = @pass)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show the ID, you have to return it back using a stored procedure.

You could of done this:

```
DECLARE @MyID int

SET @MyID = (SELECT ID FROM Login WHERE username = @user AND password = @pass)

RETURN @MyID
```

Then you can pickup that ID is an output parameter or inside of a reader and check the value.
If it exists set the label to the ID:

`MyLabel.Text = reader["ID"];`

Don't forget to check for NULLs in the case that the reader is null, also it appears you are storing passwords as plain text.  That also is a no no.  Here is an example of how to [use sprocs with C#](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx).  You need to learn how to work with datasets, datareaders, datatables, etc and how to pull data from a stored procedure.  Good luck.

Comment: @CompleteNewb - The top portion is T-SQL (SQL Server).  The bottom is C# but is easily converted to vb.net `MyLabel.Text = reader("ID")`

Comment: I'm not sure on how to convert it as I just start programming a month ago but I understand the part on SQL though

Comment: When you want to store the ID you have to ask yourself how do I get an ID from a database.  You need to select it.  When you select it you need to store back to your calling application.  So you need to read about calling stored procedures from VB.net or C#.  Do some googling and you should find some information.